# PHP - Detect gzip server response

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, gzip

I'm using curl to fetch a webpage, I need to detect if the response is gzip or not.

This works perfectly fine if Content-Encoding is specified in the response headers, but some servers instead return "Transfer-Encoding": "Chunked" and no Content-Encoding header.

Is there any way to detect gzip or get the raw (encoded) server response?

I tried looking at curl_getinfo but the content_encoding isn't specified either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if response starts with gzip magic numbers, specifically `1f 8b`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to detect gzip

Yes. You can use cURLs Header functions. For example you can define an function, which handles the header responses. Use `curl_setopt()`with the `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` option. Or write it to an file (which you have created with `fopen()`) with the `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER` option.

There may are more options you could use. Look out the possibilities at the [curl_setopt()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) manual. The header you are looking for have the name: *Content-Encoding*.

If you have the output in a file, you could also use PHPs [finfo](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) with some of its [predefined constants](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php). Or [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) (*DEPRECATED!*) if finfo is not available to you.

> [...] or get the raw (encoded) server response?

Yes. You can specify the accept-encoding header. The value you are look for is *identity*.
So you can send:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

May have look to the [HTTP/1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)
To get an unencoded/uncompressed output (for example to directly write it into a file).
Use `CURLOPT_ENCODING` for this purpose. You can set it also with *curl_setopt*.

Answer (score 1):

You can either issue a separate HEAD request:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true
CURLOPT_NOBODY => true
```

Or request the header to be prefixed to your original request:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true
```

But, if you just want to get the (decoded) HTML, you can use:

```
CURLOPT_ENCODING => ''
```

And CURL will automatically negotiate with the server and decode it for you.